# image stitching to generate a Panorama with opencv

Tags: opencv, image-stitching

Now, i'm doing the experiment with opencv to stitch several images into a panorame, but These pictures are taken at different angles. now i want to do is to project all the images onto a cylindrical surface, then using the SIFT to match the features to get the transform matrix. how should I do it? is there any interface of opencv to do that(to project all the images onto a cylindrical surface, and i don't know any parameter of the camera)?

Answer (score 0):

In the OpenCV sample folder there is a script called stitching_detailed.cpp. It does the whole pipeline for creating panoramas including feature extraction, matching, warping and blending, etc.

You should have a look on it:
https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/stitching_detailed.cpp

Comment: I know it. But i want to project my images to a cylindrical surface,is  there any interface to do that?

Comment: You can set it with the flag `warp`. E.g. `--warp=cylindrical`.